# Select2 Posting Ids instead of text

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2

I am initializing select2(multiple) with remote data (json) and when the form is submitted select2 submits the indexes of the selected text(s), can it return selected text(in comma separated like indexes) instead of indexes?

```
 <input type="hidden" id="IntendedCourses" name="IntendedCourses"/>

 $.getJSON("GetCourses.aspx", function (course) {               
                $("#IntendedCourses").select2({
                    multiple: true,
                    data: course
                });    
            });
```

json format :

```
[{"id":"0","text":"Accounting"},{"id":"1","text":"Accounting & Finance"},{"id":"2","text":"Aeronautical"},{"id":"3","text":"Aerospace Engineering"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is:

```
$("#IntendedCourses").change(function() {
    var selection = (JSON.Stringify($("#IntendedCourses").select2('data')));
});
```

This should give you the JSON for what is inside the selection upon change.

Comment: this returns JSON of what is selected for instance : [{"id":"0","text":"Accounting"},{"id":"1","text":"Accounting & Finance"}] and I only want to use the "text" object. So how do I get text only? like in above case,"Accounting,Accounting & Finance" and json.parse is returning undefined, maybe because of duplicate keys?

Comment: Too bad parsing does not work, you may have to resort to string processing manually to get text.